# Python text file manipulation using dictionaries and filters

Tags: python, list

I am trying to take text from two separate files such as:

```
File 1:
000892834     13.663      0.098      0.871      0.093      0.745      4.611       4795

File 2:
892834  4916   75   37  4857 130 128  4795  4.61 -0.09    0 0
```

and get an output such as:

```
892834     13.663      0.098      0.871      0.093      0.745      4.611       4795
892834     4916        4795       -0.09
```

I have some code that seems close to a solution:

```
filter_func_1 = lambda x: x >= 15   
filter_func_2 = lambda x: (5777 + 100) > x > (5777 - 100)
mergedData = defaultdict(list)
with open('Table1_Karoff.txt') as file_1, open('Table7_Pinsonneault.txt') as file_2, open('Processed_Data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line_1 in file_1:
            splt_file_1 = line_1.split()
            if filter_func_1(splt_file_1[1]):
                 mergedData[splt_file_1[0].lstrip('0')].append(line_1)
        for line_2 in file_2:
                splt_file_2 = line_2.split()
        Data = map(itemgetter(0, 1, 8, 9), line_2)
            if filter_func_2(splt_file_2[1]):
                 mergedData[splt_file_2[0]].append(['   '.join(map(str, i)) for i in Data])
        for k in mergedData:
            if len(mergedData[k]) == 2:
                outfile.write("\n".join(mergedData[k]) + "\n")          
        return outfile
```

what this code is 'supposed' to do is create two kinds of filters using lambda operators, compare a certain index in each line to the lambda function and see if it is true, and if so, append that entire line to a list for output. It also strips the '000' away from the beginning of the first number in file 1, and checks to make sure that the same first number is present in both files.

My Problems are:

1) The file_1 ID # (that first number) does not correctly have all of the 0's stripped from it, even though to my knowledge the code should be doing that. It outputs as 00892834, thus only removing the first 0.

2) After I added the filters, no data at all would be written to the new file, and when I checked to see if the line.split had properly created a new list, it had not, meaning that there was no data to filter because there was no data in the splt_file_# input. This is strange to me and I do not understand how that could possibly happen. I tested for the list creation by adding a writeline at the end that should have written out the splt_file_1 and splt_file_2 lists, however it did not spit out anything.

3) Since the values I needed are  not callable in the list from file 2 in order (I need indices 0, 1, 8, 9 only) I tried to map then format the data, but this gives an index out of range issue, which is understandable because of my problem in #2 above.

I need any help I can get in removing these errors, I do not know if my code is wrong or if Im just missing something, thanks for any help given.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation in the code above?

Comment: @MichaelPratt Certainly! Sorry I hadn't noticed that

Comment: Is there more than one line in the input-files? If so, do you mind reading them into memory to do the matching in memory after reading both files? Do you have any contraints on the order of these input lines?

Comment: Yes there are hundreds of lines in each file that are nicely organized in the format I showed above, and this is one of my first python scripts to mess with strings so I do not really know if it would hurt or not to have it do the matching in memory. The only constraint is that the lines from file 1 must appear above the line from file 2 with matching ID # (again, as I showed above)

Comment: Hundreds should be fine, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry not to correct your solution, but sometimes a different take can also be helpful. This would be my code, if I understand you correctly.

```
file_1_data = dict()
file_2_data = dict()
for filename, data in [('infile1.txt', file_1_data), ('infile2.txt', file_2_data)]:
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:  
        split_line = line.split()       
        first_int = int(split_line[0])
        rest_floats = [float(f) for f in split_line[1:]]
        data[first_int] = rest_floats
```

Now you have dictionaries for both files, where the keys are `int`, so you can compare those, and the values are lists of floats. After this it's pretty easy.

```
def filter_1(x):
return x > 1

def filter_2(x): 
return 4 < x < 100000

with open('outfile.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
for key in file_1_data:
    if key in file_2_data:
        #write a record, the first one
        data_to_write = [str(f) for f in file_1_data[key] if filter_1(f)]       
        record = '  '.join([str(key)] + data_to_write) + '\n'
        outfile.write(record)
        #second one, do filtering here
        data_to_write = [str(f) for f in file_2_data[key] if filter_2(f)]
        record = '  '.join([str(key)] + data_to_write) + '\n'   
        outfile.write(record)
```

Hope it helps. I think my point here is: Don't worry about being a bit verbose or on the simplistic side, just make it easy for yourself and don't repeat yourself if you can avoid it. Good luck.

Comment: Yes the output needs to look exactly as I put in the OP, and it is necessary to have the ID's in order if thats waht you mean by match

Comment: I'm sorry, but the more I read it, the less I understand your OP. What's the filtering? What's in the code doesn't really fit with the sample data you've posted. And is there really just one line in each inputfile, and do they always have an equal integer in the first column?

Comment: I think my other comment addresses this stuff :)

Comment: This is good, however I have a problem on the output side, it is coming out like this:                                              8355845  6151.0
8355845                                                               Which is not terrible but I am losing a whole bunch of necessary numbers there, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing strings to `filter_func_1` and `filter_func_2` and then comparing them with integers inside the lambdas.  But when you compare numbers and strings, the comparison is degenerate:  numerics are always considered to precede strings (this is implementation-specific; I'm assuming CPython behavior).  So your first lambda is always going to return `True` and the second `False`.  As a result, they're not functioning as filters in your code.

You need to convert the strings you pass to integers or floats, e.g.:

```
filter_func_1 = lambda x: float(x) >= 15
```

Or you could convert your input before before passing it to a filter.  In either case you should think about what you want to do when the input can't be converted to a numeric type.

Converting to a numeric type will also get rid of leading `0`s. It might or might not help with your second problem, but in any case you won't get the results you expect until you make a change to this part of your code.

Comment: Thanks for that bit of insight, any help on how I would go about converting in the way you mention?

Comment: You'll want to apply `int()` or `float()` to each piece of data (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) for their documentation). If you're happy using all floats, you could write something like: `splt_file_1 = map(float, line_1.split())`.

Comment: If I apply this to the code it works well, but I need to only pull out certain parts of file 2, I am using an itemgetter to try and do this, this is what I have:                                splt_file_2 = map(float, line_2.split())                 
splt_2_Data = map(itemgetter(0, 1, 8, 9), splt_file_2)                                                         This gives me an error however that floats have no getitem attribute, how could I fix this?

Comment: You don't want to map the `itemgetter` over the list; that's applying the `itemgetter` individually to each element of the list.  Apply it to the list object itself:  `itemgetter(0,1,8,9)(splt_file_2)`.